# how to avoid non printable characters in for each loops (shell scripting)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I wrote a shell script as follows

```
for i in `readlink -f rec*`:
do
    cd $i
    pwd
    cd ..
    pwd
done
```

The following are the details of corresponding directories:

```
readlink -f rec*

/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.1
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.2
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.3
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.4
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.5
```

---

the script output:

```
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.1
/home/sandilya/part655gib
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.2
/home/sandilya/part655gib
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.3
/home/sandilya/part655gib
/home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.4
/home/sandilya/part655gib
mvrec.sh: 5: cd: can't cd to /home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.5:
/home/sandilya/part655gib
/home/sandilya
```

---

The problem is that last directory is left out.. I was expecting that the last entry is combined with a non printable character. Permissions are all okay with the directories.
Please help me out of this mess. Thanks in advance

Comment: From the question, I can't see which character causes you problems. Try `ls --escape` in `/home/sandilya/part655gib/` and add that to your question.

Comment: to avoid any non printable character you can use `cd \`printf '%q' "$i"\``

Comment: Give here output `ls -la`

Comment: does not answer the question, just advice: check the exit status of cd: `if cd "$i"; then pwd; cd -; pwd; fi` or use a subshell so you don't change the CWD of your current shell: `(cd "$i" && pwd) && pwd`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is more apparent than it looks. There is no non-printable character.

Let's take a look a `cd` error message from `dash`, the shell you're using instead of `bash`:

```
$ cd somewhere
dash: 5: cd: can't cd to somewhere
                                  ^-- Nothing follows the path
```

Now look at your error message:

```
mvrec.sh: 5: cd: can't cd to /home/sandilya/part655gib/recup_dir.5:
                                                Spurious colon ---^
```

And where does this colon come from?

```
for i in `readlink -f rec*`:
                           ^--- Right here
```

Delete it, and it'll work.

(Note that this is not canonical or entirely correct code, and people's suggestions about `for f in rec*` loops and subshells still apply.)

Comment: yet another reason for keeping the `do` on the same line as the `for` ... then the interpreter will catch these mis-typed semicolons